# Using @Version with Envers

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, hibernate-envers

My application uses SpringBoot, Hibernate, and Spring Data JPA to make the magic happen. I'm trying to add Hibernate's Envers library onto this, to do revision tracking. However, I'm running into some conflicts between Envers and the @Version annotation.

By default, Envers will not audit any fields annotated with @Version. This makes sense to me, as @Version is just to keep track of optimistic locking, and so I don't really have a need to keep a revision history of it.

However, the issue I'm running into is that when I am getting a revision entity, it doesn't come back with the version. Which makes sense - Envers stores the revision entity in the ..._AUD table, and that table has no Version column, so obviously the entity wouldn't have a Version. The problem is that I sometimes want to use that entity as part of another transaction*, but because it doesn't have a Version, the entity is considered transient and an exception is thrown.

So I've got a few different solutions, but none of them seem ideal, so I was hoping to get some input on the best way I can accomplish this:

1. I can get the revision entity, then make a separate repository call using the id in the revision entity to get the actual entity, then just use that entity. This would add a lot of complexity (especially in determining the correct repository to use) and an extra database call that seems unnecessary.
2. I can save the Version. This isn't ideal, as it isn't really information I care about, but I can deal with it if it means a working, efficient system. I have also tried this and had problems with it (setting doNotAuditOptimsticLockingField to true in my config appears to do nothing), but if this is determined to be the best solution, I'll open a separate question to deal with it.
3. I could potentially change the repository call that is failing to use an ID rather than the actual entity, but I wouldn't be surprised if I'd have to change a number of other repository calls to make this work.

If there is a 4th option, I'm all ears!

*: The other transaction is a database call that happens when converting the entity into a resource to be returned by a REST endpoint. One of the entities I have is AccountEntity. The revision entity I get is used by this method:

```
LinkOwnerEntity findByAccountEntity(AccountEntity accountEntity);
```

And the linkOwner Entity class looks like this:

```
public class LinkOwnerEntity {

    ...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ACCOUNT_ID", unique=true, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_OWNER_ACCOUNT_ID"))
    private AccountEntity accountEntity;

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Optimistic locking is all about making sure that the data that you see is the data that you will modify. So when the user decide to restore an old version (I suppose that's what you want to do with Envers) on his screen he should see the current version of the content and the old version of the content he want to restore. You need to keep the version field of the version that the user saw as the current version and send it in your request to the application and use it for saving the modifications.

This way if the data has been modified since the user looked at it, his modifications will be denied instead of overriding someone else modifications.

Comment: My understanding of the needed functionality here is just that the user needs to read the data, not modify or restore it. That would and could be done separately, through the normally available avenues. You do make a good point though, and I will verify that this functionality is not needed. However, if it's not needed, I don't see any other need for the Version field.

Comment: User code really should not be in the habit of doing anything with the `@Version` attribute.

Comment: If the end-goal here is to restore an entity, that should boil down to first asking Hibernate to provide a managed entity (if one currently still exists) based on a PK and then using that PK to ask Envers for a specific revision.  Then OP then needs to overlay all _changed_ properties into the managed instance and then merge.  If the entity has been deleted and doesn't use a natural key, then the notion of version is irrelevant here as the new instance would be assigned a new surrogate key and would be treated as a new entity entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Before I dive into what I believe you should do, I do want to clarify a few things.

First, you really should not under no circumstance treat the instance that the Envers Query API provides you in anyway as a detached entity instance.

Depending on how you annotate your entities, its very possible that the instance you retrieve from Envers is a mix of both audited historical row data and current line table data.  It's also feasible that the instance is a subset of properties that your real entity instance manages because you may have only opted to track specific properties.

Therefore, I would not personally consider using that retrieved instance as something that I'd associate with a managed entity inside a transaction, at least not blindly.

Secondly, what isn't clear necessarily from your question is the real purpose for querying Envers in the first place and then using the result as an association in a mapping rather than simply executing a query against the real entity in the first place.

So ultimately that that brings me to my suggestion which would be your option 3 or a variant of it.

It sounds like you might want to look into using `Session#load` or `EntityManager#getReference`.  These two methods are designed to build a proxy instance based on a given identifier and then you can blindly use that proxy during an association mapping without the overhead of hydrating the instance directly (thus avoiding that database call overhead).

This approach also avoids any need to use Envers Query API here as I really fail to see the relevance of it in this use case at all based on what you've provided in your question.  If there is a specific reason to involve a Envers query, please update your question.